# How do I keep an OAuth consumer key secure on a javascript-only web application?

Tags: javascript, oauth, tumblr, github-pages

I'm trying to write a web application for Tumblr hosted on GitHub Pages that can display a user's likes. Having very little web development experience, my original approach to accessing the Tumblr API was something like this:

```
var host_name = "some-username"
var api_key = "XXX"
$.ajax({                                                                
    type: "GET",                                                        
    url: "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + host_name + ".tumblr.com/likes?api_key=" + api_key,                                                       
    dataType: "jsonp",                                                                 
    success: function(results) {
        ...
    }
});
```

This works just fine because I only need the consumer key to get the likes according to the Tumblr API. However, it occurred to me that it probably isn't a good idea to store the consumer key as a variable in my script where it is publicly accessible. Unfortunately, since GitHub Pages only hosts static sites, I can't put the consumer key on the website's server and access it whenever I make an API call to keep it secure (not that I even know how to do that). How can I keep the key secure without a dedicated server?

Comment: If you are using a front end solution to access the API then you cannot prevent exposing the api key. In one of my applications I have a separate file which contains global variables including the api key, I then make a call passing in the variable name eg: site.apiKey`. Then the only other thing I have been able to do is to unescape the key, so it is less decipherable to the human eye. You could use some conversion to make the string less readable, but the actual network call will always expose the key.

Comment: @lharby your comment is an answer. Why don't you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel well it doesn't offer any code, and it tells the OP that there is no solution to hiding an api key in the front end.

Comment: @lharby you're right. I do the same. But what do you ear by "OP" ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Original Poster http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean

Comment: Thanks for the response, answer or not. If I can't prevent prevent exposing the key, should I be fine with my previous approach?  Do I even have that much to lose if my key is exposed? It seems like any attempt to obfuscate the key can only be so effective.

Comment: I also have access to a private GitHub repository. Would it be possible to keep the key there and get it using a separate ajax call or something?